# Linq Flatten List of List

Tags: c#, linq

Using Linq what will be the best way of making a flattened list with these 2 objects lists

```
public class DataDto
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public List<ScoreDto> Scores { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreDto
{
    public string ExamID { get; set; }
    public double Mark { get; set; }
}
```

into a list that will present as

```
public class FinalDto
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string ExamID { get; set; }
    public double Mark { get; set; }
}
```

With `StudentID` repetitions for the number of `ScoreDtos` present for a particular student.

Example data -

```
var data = new List<DataDto>()
{
    new DataDto
    { 
        StudentID = "S1", 
        Scores = new List<ScoreDto>()
        { 
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "01", Mark = 5},
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "02", Mark = 15},
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "03", Mark = 25}

        }
    },
    new DataDto
    {
        StudentID = "S2",
        Scores = new List<ScoreDto>()
        {
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "01", Mark = 1},
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "02", Mark = 5},
            new ScoreDto { ExamID = "03", Mark = 20}

        }
    }
};
```

So it produces -

```
StudentID, ExamID, Mark
S1, 01, 5
S1, 02, 15
S1, 03, 25
S2, 01, 1
S2, 02, 5
S2, 03, 20
```

Comment: `var flattened = from datum in data from score in datum.Scores select new FinalDto { StudentID = datum.StudentID, ExamID = score.ExamID, Mark = score.Mark };`

Comment: Are you really looking for "_the best way_", or just "_a way_"?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks that works. Searching to see if that'll be the best approach

Comment: @atiyar, the best way. do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Riwen, it did when i checked but i had scanned here for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to flatten a list of lists:

```cs
var final = data.SelectMany(
    student => student.Scores, 
    (student, score) => new FinalDto { 
         StudentID = student.StudentID, 
         ExamID = score.ExamID, 
         Mark = score.Mark 
    }
);

Console.WriteLine("StudentID, ExamID, Mark");
foreach (var result in final)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", result.StudentID, result.ExamID, result.Mark);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a different overload of `SelectMany` along with a nested `Select` projection:

```cs
var final = data.SelectMany(
    student => student.Scores.Select(
        score => new FinalDto { 
           StudentID = student.StudentID, 
           ExamID = score.ExamID, 
           Mark = score.Mark 
        }
    )
);
```

You can also use query syntax:

```cs
var final = (
   from student in data
   from score in student.Scores
   select new FinalDto { 
       StudentID = student.StudentID,
       ExamID = score.ExamID, 
       Mark = score.Mark 
   }
);
```

Note that this is just translated to the second form shown above.

There's no "best" here. Forms two and three literally compile to the same exact code. Form one is just a slight variation. There is no impact (speed, memory) for choosing one over the other. Pick the one that is visually appealing to you. Personally I don't write query syntax (the last form) and I always forget the first overload exists so I end up using the second one.

Comment: thanks for the time, from your experience which of these will be the best way

Comment: They're all the same. There's no best. Pick which one looks/reads better to you. Two of them literally compile to the exact same code. The other is just a slight variation. There would be zero impact choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (
    from item in data
    from score in item.Scores
    select new FinalDto {
        StudentID = item.StudentID, 
        ExamID = score.ExamID,
        Mark = score.Mark
}).ToList();
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables with a one-to-many relation: every item of table A has zero or more items from table B, and every item from table B belongs to exactly one item of table A, namely the one item that the foreign key refers to.

Whenever you have this, and you want "items with their sub-items", like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders and Authors with their Books, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=net-5.0)

If you don't want the items with their sub-items, but a flat table,consider to use [Queryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=net-5.0)

Apparently you already have fetched the "Students with their zero or more Scores", and you want a flat result. In that case you use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.selectmany?view=net-5.0)

```
IEnumerable<DataDto> studentsWithTheirScores = ...
var result = studentsWithTheirScores.SelectMany(

    // parameter collectionSelector: where are the sub-items stored?
    student => student.Scores,

    // parameter resultSelector: take each student, and each one of his Scores
    // to make one new
    (student, score) => new FinalDto
    {
        StudentId = student.StudentId,
        ExamId = score.ExamId,
        Mark = score.Mark,
    });
```